# jQuery if else top of page

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I cant seem to get this to work right, only one action is firing. Any other ways to write this?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

        if ( scrollTop < 1 ) {
            $('#nav-logo').transition({ scale: 1.0, y: 0 });
        } else {
            $('#nav-logo').transition({ scale: 0.5, y: -126 });
        }

    });
```

Comment: is the ELSE statement reached or not? I mean is your issue using transition() or the ELSE statement?

Comment: what do you mean by "only one action is firing"?

Comment: it seems only the else statement is firing. When i go back to the top of the page it doesn't transition back to the original size which is the if statement.

Comment: I don't know what is this `transition()` method and how it works. If using some kind of CSS transition (like i guess), you should reset this transition

Comment: Actually i just noticed that it fired. but there was really long delay

Comment: @Hector you should provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue if you are still unable to fix it

Comment: using http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ef2h/3/) demonstrating the original problem. It is most easily noticed when scrolling by clicking and dragging on the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that your animations were running over each other. You can prevent it with something like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ef2h/5/)

```
var $nav = $('#nav-logo');
var $window = $(window);
var wasTop = true;
$window.on('scroll', function () {
    var isTop = !$window.scrollTop();
    if (isTop && !wasTop) {
        $nav.stop();
        $nav.transition({
            scale: 1.0,
            y: 0
        });
        wasTop = true;
    } else if (!isTop && wasTop) {
        $nav.stop();
        $nav.transition({
            scale: 0.5,
            y: -126
        });
        wasTop = false;
    }
});
```